# How to Send BTC from my address to another using private key

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain

I am working on project of ICO where i am generating dynamic address for Bitcoin receive purpose, I have private key for my account how i can send it to other address which API will be helpful to me.

I am not using any bitcoin wallet, I don't think wallet is required for this.

> I am not sure about this, can anyone guide me on this. I am a new to
>   bitcoin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked with this hard and come to the conclusion that we can achieve this by block monitor. This will be easier than all other options.

Comment: What is block monitor? How is it easier than other options?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any wallet software, you could install bitcoind on your local host and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493893/heres-how-to-send-raw-transaction-btc-using-bitcoin-cli-command

You could use an online version of bitcoind RPC endpoint, but I am not sure you want to submit your private key over the network.